# Uncaught module cordova/urlutil not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:56 in cordova-3.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed cordova-3.0.0 and trying to run a demo sample with phonegap
But when i try to run the application i got following error in my logcat

```
  E/Web Console(12299): Uncaught module cordova/urlutil not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:56
```

I am confused where should i start debugging , where might the exact problem located ,I have installed all the plugin to make sure that i haven't missed any of  them .

```
$cordova plugin ls

[ 'com.phonegap.plugins.bluetooth',
  'org.apache.cordova.battery-status',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.contacts',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.device-motion',
  'org.apache.cordova.device-orientation',
  'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
  'org.apache.cordova.globalization',
  'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
  'org.apache.cordova.media',
  'org.apache.cordova.media-capture',
  'org.apache.cordova.network-information',
  'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen',
  'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]
```

In my AndroidMenifest.xml I have declared

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I am compiling my project in eclipse using Android-4.2.2
Can any one help me figure out how to solve this ?

Comment: After you did `cordova plugin ls` did you ever do `cordova build`, and then point Eclipse to `myapp/platforms/android` folder?

Comment: @MBillau No , i just tried with `cordova build` right now , But why is my index.html page's content is changed after running this command ? I have lost all my changes :(

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve this problem , so i re-installed my cordova installation :(

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Did that work? 
You shouldn't have lost all of your files. When you run cordova build, it will copy the main `/myApp/www/` folder into the correct places for each platform's web assets, so it will copy over the files in `/myApp/platforms/android/assets/www` and a different place for iOS. If you want to use Eclipse to build the app (you don't need to unless you are customizing the native Java code), then after running build you open up the `assets/www` folder in Eclipse. Or you can just run the Android create script.